# VBA - Calling a subroutine using a concatenation of strings

Tags: vba

is it possible to call a subroutine in VBA using a concatenation of strings? For example

```
Sub Call_This_2019()
   ' do something
end sub

Sub From_this()
   Call ("Call_This_" + str(2019))
Sub
```

I haven't had any luck using this approach.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2695198/2127508) discusses a similar issue and may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled  'vba calling dynamic subroutine' and
I found this at  http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?36844-Solved-Dynamic-Procedure-call

```
Sub Call_This_2019()
   ' do something
   MsgBox ("Got here")
End Sub

Sub From_this()
    Dim theCallee As String
    theCallee = "Call_This_" & LTrim(Str(2019)) ' LTrim removes leading blank
    'Call theCallee         ' Syntax error
    'Call Eval(theCallee)   ' 2766 no Application object
    Application.Run theCallee
End Sub
```